# Is there a way to override the "key" function for list.max() and list.sort() in the class of the list items?

Tags: python

I have multiple subclasses of a superclass that store something in a `instance_of_a_class.value` and I override `__cmp__()` to provide reasonable `==`, `<`, `>` etc. comparisons.

However, I have multiple places in my code where I do

`min(list_of_instances_of_class, key=lambda _: _.value)` or `max(list_of_instances_of_class, key=lambda _: _.value)` and an occasional `sorted(...`

Is there a function to override in the class so that I don't have to specify the `key` function for each call to the said functions or do I need to subclass `list` and override the `max`, `min` and `sorted` methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just implement `__lt__`:

```
class Obj(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.value < other.value
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Obj(%r)' % self.value

obj_list = [Obj(2), Obj(1), Obj(4), Obj(3)]

print max(obj_list)
print min(obj_list)
print sorted(obj_list)
```

`__cmp__` is deprecated, and all of the functions that you mentioned use only `__lt__` not the other comparisons.

If for some reason you really can't have them compare this way, you can do something like:

```
from operator import attrgetter
from functools import partial

valget = attrgetter('value')

maxval = partial(max, key=valget)
minval = partial(max, key=valget)
sortedval = partial(sorted, key=valget)
sortval = partial(list.sort, key=valget)
```

Where you call them just as `maxval(obj_list)` instead of `max(obj_list)` etc., and `sortval(obj_list)` to sort in-place instead of `obj_list.sort()`

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for. Wonder why I didn't get a deprecation warning...

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, no. The simplest thing would probably be to define specific functions that you use in place of min/max/sorted. e.g.

```
from functools import partial
min_myclass = partial(min, key = operator.attrgetter('value'))
max_myclass = partial(max, key = operator.attrgetter('value'))
...
min_myclass(list_of_instances_of_myclass)
```